# stream an AWS S3 object in binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stream, amazon-s3

From what I found both libraries `aws-sdk` and `aws-s3` (Ruby) provide methods to download S3 object data only in string chunks. I'd like to be able to read it in binary chunks, so that it resembles file I/O and be more efficient. Does anyone know if there is a supported way to do it? One hack that I thought about is creating an access URL for the S3 object (S3 functionality) and download the file with some HTTP client library. What's a good library for that in Ruby?

P.S.: I need to stream data, so that I can decrypt files on-the-fly. AWS has client-side encryption library only in Java SDK.

Comment: The aws-sdk gem has since this question was originally posted added support for client side encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out in ruby (since 1.9?) a string of encoding `ASCII-8BIT` is used as a binary block, so you have to work with that. P.S.: `net/http` is a ruby http client library that can be used to read response body.